# Why don't Mark and Simon go near Tommy MacKenzie's grave?

Tags: plot-explanation, t2-trainspotting

In *[T2 Trainspotting](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2763304/)*, Spud is putting his flowers on Tommy MacKenzie's grave, but Mark & Simon are standing so far from it.

**Why are Mark and Simon standing so far away from the grave?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably out of remorse at least on Mark's part, I am not sure about Simon.

Mark is the one who "helped" Tommy take drugs for the first time, leading him to become addicted, catching AIDS and then dying.

Here's what Simon says to Mark at around 1:11:19 :

```
How about the time you sold Tommy his very first hit, leading him on to heroin addiction, HIV infection  and ultimately his death at the age of...What was it, 22, 23?
```